# How to aggregate NumPy record array (sum, min, max, etc.)?

Tags: python, numpy, aggregate-functions, aggregate, recarray

Consider a simple record array structure:

```
import numpy as np
ijv_dtype = [
    ('I', 'i'),
    ('J', 'i'),
    ('v', 'd'),
]
ijv = np.array([
    (0, 0, 3.3),
    (0, 1, 1.1),
    (0, 1, 4.4),
    (1, 1, 2.2),
    ], ijv_dtype)
print(ijv)  # [(0, 0, 3.3) (0, 1, 1.1) (0, 1, 4.4) (1, 1, 2.2)]
```

I'd like to [aggregate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) certain statistics (sum, min, max, etc.) from `v` by grouping unique combinations of `I` and `J`. Thinking from SQL, the expected result is:

```
select i, j, sum(v) as v from ijv group by i, j;
 i | j |  v
---+---+-----
 0 | 0 | 3.3
 0 | 1 | 5.5
 1 | 1 | 2.2
```

(the order is not important)

The best I can think up for NumPy is ugly, and I'm not confident I've ordered the result correctly (although it seems to work here):

```
# Get unique groups, index and inverse
u_ij, idx_ij, inv_ij = np.unique(ijv[['I', 'J']], return_index=True, return_inverse=True)
# Assemble aggregate
a_ijv = np.zeros(len(u_ij), ijv_dtype)
a_ijv['I'] = u_ij['I']
a_ijv['J'] = u_ij['J']
a_ijv['v'] = [ijv['v'][inv_ij == i].sum() for i in range(len(u_ij))]
print(a_ijv)  # [(0, 0, 3.3) (0, 1, 5.5) (1, 1, 2.2)]
```

I'd like to think there is a better way to do this! I'm using NumPy 1.4.1.

Comment: My first try would be to collect the data in a `collections.default_dict(list)`, using `(i,j)` tuples as keys.  Then I could preform the needed statistics on each of the lists.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` is a bit too low-level for tasks like this. I think your solution is fine if you have to use pure `numpy`, but if you don't mind using something with higher level of abstraction, try [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'I': (0, 0, 0, 1),
    'J': (0, 1, 1, 1),
    'v': (3.3, 1.1, 4.4, 2.2)})

print(df)
print(df.groupby(['I', 'J']).sum())
```

Output:

```
   I  J    v
0  0  0  3.3
1  0  1  1.1
2  0  1  4.4
3  1  1  2.2
       v
I J     
0 0  3.3
  1  5.5
1 1  2.2
```

Comment: With an early `numpy` version, `pandas` might not be an option.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a huge step up from what you have already but it at least gets rid of the for loop.

```
# Starting with your original setup

# Get the unique ij values and the mapping from ungrouped to grouped.
u_ij, inv_ij = np.unique(ijv[['I', 'J']], return_inverse=True)

# Create a totals array. You could do the fancy ijv_dtype thing if you wanted.
totals = np.zeros_like(u_ij.shape)

# Here's the magic bit. You can think of it as 
# totals[inv_ij] += ijv["v"] 
# except the above doesn't behave as expected sadly.
np.add.at(totals, inv_ij, ijv["v"])

print(totals)
```

The fact that you are using numpy's multi-dtype thing is a bit of an indicator you should be using pandas. It generally makes for less awkward code when trying to keep your `i`s, `j`s and `v`s together.